# How to parse JSON with only one key

Tags: json

I have one [json](/questions/tagged/json)file as follows.

**data.json:**

```
[{
    "id": "plot"
  },
  [
    [195, 200, 0.3],
    [196, 196, 1],
    [196, 197, 0.9],
    [196, 198, 0.1]
  ]
]
```

I am trying to parse the title of [json](/questions/tagged/json)using following code.

**code:**

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(data);
  alert(obj.id);
});
```

But i get no output while using above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
obj[0].id; // Array of object.
```